# Program that asks user how many times it wants to loop for (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

// Create a full program in eclipse that will ask the user how  times would you like to loop for. It will ask in the for loop for a rate in double value and a time in integer value. It will calculate the distance for each of the times you enter in the rate and the time.//

my current output gives me the correct answer if i only want to put in once, as it only has to run the program once. Whenever i input more than 1, It starts acting weird and thats the best way i can explain it because i don't know whats wrong with it.

Here is one random output

```
How many times would you like to calculate the distance.
12
Enter rate
2
Enter time
13
The distance is 26.0
Enter rate
12
Enter time
12
The distance is 144.0
How many times would you like to calculate the distance.
1
Enter rate
12
Enter time
1
The distance is 12.0
```

// my actual code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class NTC {
 public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop = 10;
    double rate=0;
    int time=0;
    int count;
    double distance = rate*time;

 for (count = 0; count <= loop; count++) {

 System.out.println("How many times would you like to calculate the distance.");
 loop = kb.nextInt(); 


for(rate=0; rate <loop;rate++)
{
System.out.println("Enter rate");
rate = kb.nextDouble();

for(time=0; time <loop;time++)
{
     System.out.println("Enter time");
    time = kb.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The distance is "+rate*time);

}
```

Comment: `It starts acting weird` ... and this is where you start debugging. Either printing variables or using an actual debugger. Do you go to your doctor and say "I dunno doc - I just feel weird. Give me some drugs to fix it. Thanks".

Comment: Sounds like the problem is just asking for `rate * time = distance`. Why do you have 2 other loops that iterate from `0 < loop` where `loop` is set to 10?

Comment: you don't need to be condescending. It's my first time doing a code like this in  my life, thanks for the guidance though. @GhostCat

Comment: The problem is your misconception assuming this site is for total newbies. But it is not... But you are also correct, my words were too harsh.

Comment: the formula isn't the part that was messed up, it was everything before it. I was under the assumption I had to do the for loops over and over again when i didn't. also i was trying to change little things to see if it would work better than the previous code did. The code i uploaded was the best working code I came up with before i decided to post here @Wilson

Answer (score 1):

You need to have only one `for` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NTC 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
int loop = 10;
double rate=0;
int time=0;
int count;
double distance = rate*time;
System.out.println("How many times would you like to calculate the distance.");
loop = kb.nextInt(); 
for (count = 0; count < loop; count++) 
{    
 System.out.println("Enter rate");
 rate = kb.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Enter time");
 time = kb.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The distance is "+(rate*time));
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you A LOT for helping me. It's my first programming past and my first time doing an assignment like this by myself.

Comment: Make sure to upvote my answer once you tried out my code.

Comment: He has a reputation of 1,and just collected 6 downvotes. He can't upvote, only accept.

Comment: I tried to up vote you and because like he said i have reputation of one and 6 down votes it doesn't show up publicly.

Comment: Is that so? Ok then. No problem.